# Checking if a word is a palindrome

Tags: python, palindrome

I am writing a function to check if a word is a palindrome

```
def palidrome(b):
    word = ''.join(reversed(b))
    if b == word:
        return True
    return False


def main():
    so = input("Please enter a matching word")
    come = palidrome(so)
    print(come)

main()
```

Whatever I put, e.g., 'mom,' 'dad' or 'racecar,' it always outputs `False` but it should be `True`.

Comment: Your code is working fine just problem in input staement. I will also suggest you to store string in list and than start traversing it from left and right end simultaneously. And just check that their values are equal. This will reduce time of computation.

Comment: No directly for your question, however, it is very inefficient code... Isn't it better to compare a front half and a back half?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this demo](https://repl.it/repls/UnrealisticWeightyFiletype), your code is running fine - however, I noticed your input statement doesn't have a space after it. Are you typing a space before you put your word in? If so, consider the [`strip()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/strip) function, which will remove leading and trailing spaces - or just add a space to your input prompt!

Answer (score 1):

```
 def checkPalindrome(word):
       wordCopy = word[::-1]
       if word == wordCopy:
         return True
       else:
         return False
  def main():
      s = 'oro'
      print(checkPalindrome(s))
  main()
```